# Color GridView Expiration Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am "new" in C# programming and i am trying to color the date which will expire in few days or it is already expired. This is my code

```
SqlConnection cs2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\Nikola\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Gym Software\Gym Software\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select DatumIstice FROM Korisnici", cs2);
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var expirationDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    var sevenDayBefore = expirationDate.AddDays(-7);
    if (now > sevenDayBefore && now < expirationDate)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else if (now > expirationDate)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

The last row shoud be colored, but its not: [image: example]

Comment: On what date did you take that screenshot? Because 'when' affects the outcome of your code. This makes it harder to identify the problems. One possible issue I can see is that your code will not colour a row if now == expirationDate. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
row.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this - assuming the expiration date is `Datumlsteka`, you should be selecting Value from `4th` column, `not 0th` column and use it as `expirationDate`

```
    SqlConnection cs2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\Nikola\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Gym Software\Gym Software\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select DatumIstice FROM Korisnici", cs2);
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var expirationDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
    var sevenDayBefore = expirationDate.AddDays(-7);

    if (now > sevenDayBefore && now < expirationDate)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else if (now > expirationDate)
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but still the same thind, nothing is red..or yellow.. http://prntscr.com/6pdoe5

Comment: Can you check what you are getting as value for expirationDate please?

Comment: I did it. I put the button for checking, and its working lol...all the time, the code was under Form1_Load...now its working. Thanks buddy. :)